# How to display several icons in row

Tags: android, image, listview

I have a button. It calls another activity with custom listView, that contain images and checkBoxes, marked positions are passed to another activity. It's works well, but I need that retrieved several icons to be displayed in a row into the button, as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a xml file named `row_lauout.xml` and use `LinearLayout` in it with `orientation horizontal` and arrange all your button in that.

in your `main.xml` create a `List` and aligned it as per your design.

in java code write a class called `ListAdapter` which extends either `BaseAdapter`(or any other adapter based on your need) and override `getView` method.

inside `getView` method inflate row_layout.xml as

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,
            null);
```

then implement `onClick` for all buttons in `getView` method.

one more suggestion search for **cell reuse concept in android**. it will help to make scroll very smooth.

Comment: It's almost not what I want, but It helped me to find right way =)

Answer (score 0):

Put ImageViews in a LinearLayout?  Your question is really hard to understand, but if I take it at face value that's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML layout, use a `LinearLayout` with a Horizontal orientation.

The items that you place within the container should have a fixed width or set to `wrap_content`